# How can I fix Ubuntu Minecraft constantly turning off fullscreen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While playing Minecraft on Ubuntu, I have to repeatedly tap F11 to make the game go fullscreen, and when it finally does go, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (to sprint jump) or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, it goes back to window mode. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi there. It might help if you were a bit more specific on what exact problems you are running into. Why do you have to tap F11, and what do you mean when you say it 'goes'?

Comment: That's something for superuser, since it's a problem with Ubuntu, not the game itself. Other than that a few more details would help. Like Ubuntu version, virtual or real installation, graphic card/driver, command line parameters,..

Comment: It might be the way to switch input languages. [See here.](https://makandracards.com/makandra/32615-ubuntu-make-ctrl-space-work-in-rubymine-emacs-or-other-tools)

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu also, and I experienced similar problems. Generally, I found that full screen mode flickered a lot in Ubuntu, and although I didn't have your same problems, I was having a generally bad time.

I'd recommend going into **compiz-config** (It should be installed by default, if it isn't, install it), going into OpenGL settings, and make sure that OpenGL is actually on. I know, you didn't ask this question specifically, but I'm telling you, you will experience this issue later on :D.

As for your specific problem, you have two options really. The first, simpler one is to rebind your keys. I have my sprint key set to X not CTRL, because CTRL will often disrupt me XD.

The harder way is to go into **Settings Manager > Keyboard > Shortcuts** and looking for & disabling the CTRL-Space shortcut, whatever that does.

I'm guessing what's going on is CTRL-Space is opening some window or doing some thing the sets the window focus to the desktop, and when that happens, Minecraft will automatically exit full screen mode (This is an actual feature of Minecraft, not Ubuntu).

Hope this helps!